# User class threw exception: java.util.NoSuchElementException: spark.driver.memory

Tags: apache-spark

I am getting an below error while running the Intellij application. Does any body know why this is failing?

User class threw exception: java.util.NoSuchElementException: spark.driver.memory

Comment: Difficult to say without the code you use but probably in some place your app looks for `spark.driver.memory` key and it doesn't find it. But please give some more context.

Comment: this exception is because of code or any configuration i need to change on Apache Spark.

Comment: I am using  inside the code to get the driver memory below like this Driver memory: " + sparkSession.sparkContext.getConf.get("spark.driver.memory")

Comment: please share full stack trace and relevant code.

Comment: I believe when you run it through intellij, it'll spawn a different JVM and it's memory parameter will be controlled by the `-xmX` property and not `spark.driver.memory` or `--driver-memory`

Answer (score 0):

The error is thrown by this method:

```
/** Get a parameter; throws a NoSuchElementException if it's not set */
def get(key: String): String = {
  getOption(key).getOrElse(throw new NoSuchElementException(key))
}
// SparkConf.scala
```

Thus, probably you didn't specify `spark.driver.memory` configuration entry explicitly. Can you tell how do you submit the job ? What options are passed to `spark-submit` command ?